# Defining Datasource in TomEE

Tags: apache-tomee

I am TomEE administrator and i wanted my application team to package resource configuration inside of their application, i.e. /META-INF/context.xml. Apparently this not working with TomEE, i know its working for my other Tomcat applications.
While doing so the i am getting "Unable to find the DataSource" exception.

I know some people recommended to put resource config in ../conf/tomee.xml. But i want application team to put inside war file so we can enable automation and all AD team has to do is deploy war file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add deployXML and copyXML attribute to Host element in server.xml and set their value to true as followed

```
<Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" copyXML="true" deployXML="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true" xmlBase="conf/Catalina/localhost">
```